# How can I access these controls from a different class?

Tags: c#

I have a form (Edit) with some textbox controls as private members with public properties that I want to access from another class (PatientService) and I can't figure out how to overcome the "textbox does not exist in the current context" errors for the 8 controls I am trying to access.  Also, is passing these values through the constructor a good way of doing this?  I cannot have any other part of my project aside from the PatientService class interacting with the database.  Thanks and the textboxes in question are in bold.

```
public partial class Edit : XtraForm

    {
        private string patientID;
        private string firstName;
        private string lastName;
        private string address;
        private string city;
        private string state;
        private string zipCode;
        private string phone;

        public Edit(string PatientID, string FirstName, string LastName, string Address, string City, string State, string ZipCode, string Phone)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            patientID = txtPatientID.Text;
            firstName = txtFirstName.Text;
            lastName = txtLastName.Text;
            address = txtAddress.Text;
            city = txtCity.Text;
            state = txtState.Text;
            zipCode = txtZipCode.Text;
            phone = txtPhone.Text;

        }

        public string PatientID 
        {

            get { return patientID; }
            set { patientID = value; }


        }
        public string FirstName
        {

            get { return firstName; }
            set { firstName = value; }

        }
        public string LastName
        {

            get { return lastName; }
            set { lastName = value; }

        }
        public string Address
        {

            get { return address; }
            set { address = value; }

        }
        public string City
        {

            get { return city; }
            set { city = value; }

        }
        public string State
        {

            get { return state; }
            set { state = value; }

        }
        public string ZipCode
        {

            get { return txtZipCode.Text; }
            set { txtZipCode.Text = value; }

        }
        public string Phone
        {

            get { return phone; }
            set { phone = value; }

        }

public void CreatePatient()
            {

                //SAConnection conn = new SAConnection("dsn={SQL Anywhere 10};uid=dba;pwd=sql;databasefile=C:\\Users\\Kbaker1\\Desktop\\Training1.db;");
                //SACommand cmd = new SACommand("INSERT INTO patient(patient_id, first_name, last_name, address, city, state, zipcode, phone) VALUES(); ");

                using (SAConnection conn = new SAConnection())
                {
                  conn.ConnectionString = "dsn={SQL Anywhere 10};uid=dba;pwd=sql;databasefile=C:\\Users\\Kbaker1\\Desktop\\Training1.db;";
                    conn.Open();

                    using (SACommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText =
                        "insert into patient(\n" +
                        "  patient_id,\n" +
                        "  first_name,\n" +
                        "  last_name,\n" +
                        "  address,\n" +
                        "  city,\n" +
                        "  state,\n" +
                        "  zipcode,\n" +
                        "  phone)\n" +
                        "  values(\n" +
                        "  @prm_patient_id,\n" +
                        "  @prm_first_name,\n" +
                        "  @prm_last_name,\n" +
                        "  @prm_address,\n" +
                        "  @prm_city,\n" +
                        "  @prm_state,\n" +
                        "  @prm_zipcode,\n" +
                        "  @prm_phone)";

cmd.Parameters.Add("@prm_patient_id", SADbType.VarChar, 80).Value = **txtPatientID.Text**;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@prm_first_name", SADbType.VarChar, 80).Value = **txtFirstName.Text**;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@prm_last_name", SADbType.VarChar, 80).Value = **txtLastName.Text**;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@prm_address", SADbType.VarChar, 80).Value = **txtAddress.Text**;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@prm_city", SADbType.VarChar, 80).Value = **txtCity.Text**;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@prm_state", SADbType.VarChar, 80).Value = **txtState.Text**;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@prm_zipode", SADbType.VarChar, 80).Value = **txtZipCode.Text**;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@prm_phone", SADbType.VarChar, 80).Value = **txtPhone.Text**;

                   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }
                }
            }
```

Ok, so I'm still a little confused.  I made the Patient class and instantiated it in the Edit form just like this.

public Patient pat;

```
    public Edit(Patient patient)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pat = patient;
    }
```

I'm trying to get it to when I click on an "OK" button, the textbox controls are inserted into the database via a CreatePatient method in the PatientService class.

Here is the method from the Edit Form that invokes the CreatePatient method in the PatientService class:

private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        PatientService ps = new PatientService();
        ps.CreatePatient();
     }
```

My Patient class looks like:

public class Patient 
    {

```
    List<Patient> patList = new List<Patient>();
    private string patientID;
    private string firstName;
    private string lastName;
    private string address;
    private string city;
    private string state;
    private string zipCode;
    private string phone;
    private int classificationID;
    protected object Dispose;

    public Patient(string PatientID, string FirstName, string LastName, string Address, string City, string State, string ZipCode, string Phone, int ClassificationID)
    {
        this.patientID = PatientID;
        this.firstName = FirstName;
        this.lastName = LastName;
        this.address = Address;
        this.city = City;
        this.state = State;
        this.zipCode = ZipCode;
        this.phone = Phone;
        this.classificationID = ClassificationID;

    }


      public string PatientId
    {
        get { return patientID; }
        set { patientID = value; }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return firstName; }
        set { firstName = value; }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return lastName; }
        set { lastName = value; }
    }

    public string Address
    {
        get { return address; }
        set { address = value; }
    }

    public string City
    {
        get { return city; }
        set { city = value; }
    }

    public string State
    {
        get { return state; }
        set { state = value; }
    }

    public string ZipCode
    {
        get { return zipCode; }
        set { zipCode = value; }
    }

    public string Phone
    {
        get { return phone; }
        set { phone = value; }
    }

    public int ClassificationID
    {
        get { return classificationID; }
        set { classificationID = value; }

    }

    public Patient(string PatientID)
    {
        this.patientID = PatientID;
    }

    public Patient()
    {

    }

}
```

}

So considering I am no longer passing values through the Edit constructor like in the beginning, how would I make use of the Patient class to get the textbox values sent to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to access your controls from other form, or class.
Since you have public properties, you can access to it from parent form:

```
Edit form = new Edit(patientId, ...);
//after using form
string patientId = form.PatientID;
```

Better option is wrap your fields into a single object, like entity

```
public class Patient
{
        private string patientID;
        private string firstName;
        private string lastName;
        private string address;
        private string city;
        private string state;
        private string zipCode;
        private string phone;

        //put here your properties
}
```

Use it in your Edit form

```
public partial class Edit : XtraForm
{
    public Patient Patient;

    public Edit() //empty constructor if you want to pass data manually via property
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Edit(Patient patient)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Patient = patient;
    }

    //full code here
}
```

You can always keep actual data in Patient object using `EditValueChanged` event form your text boxes (As far as I know you are using DevExpress controls, like XtraForm). For example:

```
private void txtPatientID_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Patient.patientId = txtPatientID.Text;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the string value in the "" is supposed to represent.  Would the code look like this:  Edit ed = new Edit();
                    ed.PatientID = "1";
                    ed.FirstName = "2";
                    ed.LastName = "3";
                    ed.Address = "4";
                    ed.City = "5";
                    ed.State = "6";
                    ed.ZipCode = "7";
                    ed.Phone = "8";

Answer (score 1):

You need  to pass your form class to `PatientService`
For example:

```
public class PatientService
{
    //your code
    public Edit EditForm{get;set;}
}
```

Now you can pass Edit to PatientService:
somewhere:

```
var svc = new PatientService();
svc.EditForm = existEditForm;
```

You can access tour edit form from patient service now. Something like this:

```
EditForm.PatientId = "0";
```